# Fail to randomize java string array

Tags: java

I want to randomize or shuffle the order of the string array using the code below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str[]= {"Vxds", "Cvda", "Xcgi", "Atdr", "Mbeds", "0bda"};
        String strTmp[]=str;
        
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
            list.add(new Integer(i));
        }
        
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        
        for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
            strTmp[i]=str[list.get(i)];
            System.out.println(strTmp[i]);
        }
    }
```

The reason I do it like this instead of print it out directly is because I want to make it into a function later on. That's why I passed it to strTmp[] as that is what I want the function to return. But, the code just didn't function as I expected. It prints out several same value. How can I do it the right way? Thanks for the answer...

Comment: Please add the actual and the expected output to the question.

Comment: Well, yeah, if you roll a dice multiple times, values will repeat. You 'd need to remove every item you' ve picked from str[] to guarantee uniqueness, and only then select the next item.

Comment: Also, minor nitpick: use Integer.valueOf(i) rather than new Integer(i).

Comment: Also, the minor nitpick mentioned by Taschi is promoted to major nitpick: in newer Java versions (since Java 9), the `Integer(int)` constructor is **deprecated**. You should always use `valueOf(int)`.

Comment: Further, while it is *allowed* to put the array brackets behind the variable name, it is better to put them behind the component type, as the brackets are part of the type rather than the variable name, e.g. `String[] str` instead of `String str[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it, but you are referencing the same array twice and swap the contents of it. Change this line

```
 String strTmp[] = str;
```

to

```
 String strTmp[] = new String[str.length];
```

Comment: I like this answer because it shows the main "gotcha" in the original code (and the fix). To restate the point that "strTmp" should be a reference to a separate new array, not a reference to the original array.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `String strTmp[]=str;`, both `str` and `strTmp` are references to *the same* array. So when putting elements in, you are overwriting old elements including those have not yet been moved.

You may just do

```
    String str[]= {"Vxds", "Cvda", "Xcgi", "Atdr", "Mbeds", "0bda"};
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(str));
```

This works because `Arrays.asList()` does not create a new list, it merely provides a list view on the array. Any changes to the list change the array. Including shuffling it. Edit: This works for an array of strings and an array of any other reference type. As WJS points out, this will not work for an array of primitives (e.g., `int[]`) since `Arrays.asList(arrayOfPrimitives)` will create a list view of a newly created array of *one* elemeent, the primitive array.

If you require a *new* array with the shuffled strings and the old array unmodified, the solution is:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str));
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    String[] newStr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
    
    System.out.println("Original array:     " + Arrays.toString(str));
    System.out.println("New shuffled array: " + Arrays.toString(newStr));
```

Edit: Output from one example run:

> ```
> Original array:     [Vxds, Cvda, Xcgi, Atdr, Mbeds, 0bda]
> New shuffled array: [0bda, Cvda, Mbeds, Vxds, Xcgi, Atdr]
> ```

As you can see, the original array is unmodified.

Edit: Since Java 11 it’s nicer to create the new array using `Collection.toArray(IntFunction<String[]>)`:

```
    String[] newStr = list.toArray(String[]::new);
```

[See both code snippets run live in IdeOne](https://ideone.com/nISsIe).

Comment: Be careful with  promoting `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));`  Since `Arrays.asList(arr)` does not support primitive arrays, the above will quietly fail by shuffling a `List` of one item.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the array `str`.  Try this.

```
String str[] = {"Vxds", "Cvda", "Xcgi", "Atdr", "Mbeds", "0bda"};
String strTmp[] = str.clone();
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(strTmp));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strTmp));
```

output

```
[Xcgi, Cvda, Atdr, Mbeds, 0bda, Vxds]
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to randomized your array in every execute. Here is the code for this.

```
import java.util.*;    

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str[]= {"Vxds", "Cvda", "Xcgi", "Atdr", "Mbeds", "0bda"};    
        List<String> list =Arrays.asList(str);
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        System.out.println(list);
     }
```